# Viewing server logs in Eclipse when running a MobileFirst Hybrid App on Android Emulator

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am running an IBM MobileFirst Platform Hybrid App in the Android Emulator.

I want to see the debug messages in Eclipse Console (WL.Logger.debug() statements in main.js). Is this possible?

When I run the same app in Xcode on an iOS simulator,I can see these debug messages in Xcode's console.

Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look in LogCat...?

In Eclipse, go to Window > Show View > Other... > search for "LogCat".
Now when you run your application in the Android Emulator (or a physical device, doesn't matter), simply make sure to look in the LogCat view.

You may need to first select the device from the "Devices" view (add it as well while adding the "LogCat" view).

You will then see `WL.Logger.debug` statements from any client-side file (not adapters) in the LogCat.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Mr.Idan Adar. There is nothing in the LogCat. It is set to "verbose" but still nothing is displayed.

Comment: It tested this myself in MFPF 7.0; I placed in wlCommonInit() a "WL.Logger.debug("***** test");" and could see it in LogCat.

Comment: I did the same test.Created a new MobileFirst Hybrid Application.Added the debug statements and then "Run on MobileFirst Server".Nothing happens in LogCat.

Comment: Well then, I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I feel very embarrassed now.It started working after restarting the eclipse.I am able to see the logs in LogCat for both the dummy application and my actual app also.Thanks again